# Java String immutable

Tags: java, string

I was thinking about string in java. String are immutable. But when the code is mutable

```
String str = new String("abc");
System.out.println(str.toUpperCase());
System.out.println(str);
```

The outout is

```
ABC
abc
```

Actually the output should be

```
ABC
ABC
```

because String are immutable. Please explain. Thanks!

Comment: When you call the java String methods you are actually doing new String.

Comment: @Jar Var I think you  are confused  with term  mutable and immutable  in OOP please refer http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/214167/understanding-the-difference-between-mutable-and-immutable-classes

Answer (score 5):

No, the output is what it is precisely *because* strings are immutable. Calling `toUpperCase()` doesn't change the contents of the existing string, it creates a new one and returns a reference to that... it *has* to do that, due to strings being immutable.

This isn't just the case for `toUpperCase()` - all methods on `String` that sound like they might modify the string (e.g. `trim()`) actually return a new one instead.

Compare that with the *mutable* class `StringBuilder`, where the object *is* modified, and a reference to `this` is returned:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("abc");
        System.out.println(builder); // abc
        System.out.println(builder.append("def")); // abcdef
        System.out.println(builder); // abcdef
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually,

```
str.toUpperCase()
```

returns a new `String` object. Therefore you get an **uppercased** String as output. But if you try to print `str` to the console, you'll see that it's value never changed.

If you try:

```
str = str.toUpperCase();
System.out.println(str);
// System.out: ABC
```